# UsersController Method Error 'title'. No Title in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Reposting due to formatting errors in previous post.

I am getting the below error, I've added code below for the whole MVC. The strange thing here is the controller wants a 'title' method to be included but I don't have a title requirement anywhere else, could this be referring to something else. While this isn't working the def update method won't patch so I can't save any user updates or new data to the system (it's a HRIS system btw).

So the error is;

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#update
undefined method `title' for #<User:0x007ff3dd9f8a70>

Extracted source (around line #56):
54
55
56
57
58
59

 def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
     flash[:success] = "Information Updated"
     redirect_to @user
     #handle successful update
```

Here is my Schema;

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "employee"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.date     "startdate"
    t.date     "probationcomp"
    t.date     "annualreview"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "phonenumber"
    t.string   "nextofkin"
    t.string   "kinnumber"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",               default: false
    t.string   "leavenum"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.boolean  "hstrain"
    t.boolean  "induction"
    t.boolean  "lhtrain"
    t.boolean  "vodatotal"
    t.boolean  "commtrainops"
    t.boolean  "commtrainsell"
    t.boolean  "hosttrainops"
    t.boolean  "hosttrainsell"
    t.boolean  "cpstrainops"
    t.boolean  "cpstops"
    t.boolean  "cpstsell"
    t.string   "leaverem"
    t.text     "specialism"
    t.string   "shelf"
    t.string   "doc_file_name"
    t.string   "doc_content_type"
    t.integer  "doc_file_size"
    t.datetime "doc_updated_at"
  end
```

The view;

```
<h1>Change your profile settings</h1>

<div class="row">
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<!-- left side -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :address, "Home Address" %>
      <%= f.text_area :address, :cols => "1", :rows => "5", class: "form-control" %>

      </div>
<!-- right side -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :phonenumber, "Contact Number" %>
      <%= f.text_field :phonenumber, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= f.label :nextofkin, "Emergency Contact Person" %>
      <%= f.text_field :nextofkin, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= f.label :kinnumber, "Emergency Contact Phone Number" %>
      <%= f.text_field :kinnumber, class: "form-control" %>


      <div class="gravatar_edit">
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <a href="https://gravatar.com/emails" target=_blank>Change Profile Pic</a>
      </div><br><p><br>
      <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: 'btn btn-warning' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller (this is where I think the error is, though update function looks fine, I haven't posted the whole controller, but can do if it helps)

```
def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
     flash[:success] = "Information Updated"
     redirect_to @user
     #handle successful update
   else
     render 'edit'
 end
end

private
          def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :employee, :email, :password, :startdate, :probationcomp,
                         :password_confirmation, :annualreview, :address, :phonenumber, :nextofkin, :kinnumber,
                         :created_at, :updated_at, :password_digest, :admin, :leavenum, :avatar_file_name, :avatar_content_type, :avatar_file_size,
                         :avatar_updated_at, :hstrain, :induction, :lhtrain, :vodatotal, :commtrainops, :commtrainsell, :hosttrainops,
                         :hosttrainsell, :cpstrainops, :cpstops, :cpstsell, :leaverem, :specialism, :shelf, :doc_file_name, :doc_content_type,
                         :doc_file_size, :doc_updated_at)
          end
```

Finally the model;

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 7 }, allow_nil: true
  #set up "uploaded_file" field as attached_file (using Paperclip)

  searchable do
    text :name, :id, :phonenumber
  end

  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  def authenticated?
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_token, nil)
  end

end
```

I'm sure someone has had this issue before, just can't see the wood for the trees. test script comes back with same error.

Comment: can you post server log also?

Comment: @DanM
Also can you post your `users#show` template and `routes.rb`?

Comment: Trying searching your application code for `title`. Or read the error message more closely as it will tell you exactly where the error occurred. A simple search tells me that its not in anything you have posted. http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace

Comment: Many thanks for posting back, this is actually useful! I've used rails cast before and found it very helpful so I'll try to trace the error back. DanM

Comment: sorted, I removed functions attached to sunspot and Solr search which I'll enable again in full next time I get a chance, but the core update function is working again now, having checked the stack. Many thanks Again!!!